# How to tell a test under cmake/ctest where to find its input data ... without changing hard-coded file names

Tags: cmake, ctest

Directory `prj/test` contains some test scripts `t01.exe`, `t02.exe` etc. Some of them need input data `d01.dat` etc, also provided in `prj/test`. The names of these data files are hard-coded in the tests, and I cannot easily change this. The control file `CMakeLists.txt` contains

```
enable_testing()
file(GLOB test_sources "t*")
foreach(test_src ${test_sources})
    string(REGEX REPLACE ".*/" "" test_name "${test_src}")
    string(REGEX REPLACE ".exe$" "" test_name "${test_name}")
    add_test(${test_name} "${test_src}")
endforeach(test_src)
```

I'm building the project in a subdirectory `prj/build`. `ctest` works fine ... until a test requires input data. Obviously, they are not found because they reside in `prj/test` whereas the test runs in `prj/build/test`.

Hence my questions:

- What's the standard way to let the tests find their input data?
- Is there a way that does not require copying the data (in case they are huge)?
- True that symlinks don't work under Windows, and therefore are no acceptable solution?

Comment: `add_test` command accepts `WORKING_DIRECTORY`option. You can set this option to `prj/test` (`${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test`) directory, so test will be run from directory where it is located. As I understand from your question, such way test will find data files.

Comment: Great, many thanks! `add_test(NAME ${test_name} COMMAND "${test_src}" WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` works perfectly. Will you repost your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`add_test` command accepts `WORKING_DIRECTORY` option. You can set this option to a directory where a test is located. So, the test will find its data file:

```
add_test(NAME ${test_name} COMMAND "${test_src}"
         WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

Comment: Very helpful! Note that this doesn't set the working directory of the *executable* when used in Visual Studio. You might want to add `set_target_properties(${test_name} PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` when running the executables individually from your IDE.

Answer (score 3):

The variables `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` and `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` are helpful. The first one is the source directory to the current binary location. The latter is the root to the top level of the source tree.

Supposed you have an input file at `prj/test/inputfile` you could get the path to it with`${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inputfile`. You can pass the path as an argument to your test.

Comment: `inputfile` nowhere appears in my `CMakeLists.txt`, and I would hesitate to make it appear since that might require extra work for any test added later.

Comment: `inputfile` was an example for any input file you have. You can pass this as an argument to your test. I extended my answer.

Comment: My tests are in a domain-specific language that does not easily admit this solution. I should have said it more explicitely, and now edited the question: Input file names are hard-coded in the tests, and I would rather not change this. I really need a solution at cmake or wrapper shell script level.

Comment: Ok, you don't want to copy the data nor do you want to symlink to them. Additionally, a path to the right location does not work for you. Then there is no other way. Don't use out-of-source builds? A poor advice.

Comment: Copying is allowed in question 1. Concerning symlinks, see question 3.

Comment: Ah ok. Then I'd say giving the path to your test is what I would consider the standard way.